# how to prevent Oauth Access reply attack

Tags: oauth-2.0

I utilize the access token obtained upon successful social OAuth2.0 authentication, such as Discord, to authenticate users on my platform. However, I am concerned that the access token may be susceptible to retrieval through phishing attacks by malicious actors. These individuals could potentially obtain the user access token by engaging in OAuth on their platform, posing a security risk.

Is there any way to verify that the access token is issued, was from my client?

Comment: Hypothetically, what do you perceive as the risk of getting a _different_ also valid access token? Aside from that you can use the `state` parameter during the `auhtorization_code` flow to validate that you initiated the flow.